# Testflight new builds not available for testers

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I uploaded an app on Testflight using Xcode (Build 1.1.0) and it was available to the testers. But now this version has been expired and new versions (1.1.1 - 1.1.3) are not available to them:

[image]

I have tried opening the newer build links and it says:

[image]
I clearly have Internal testers added to my account. How can I fix this problem and make the latest builds accessible to the developers?

Comment: Did you choose the right version under "TestFlight > Testing > Internal Testing"? Are the internal testers listed there? Which version did you choose for "Select Version to Test"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps indicated in image and you can add testers and then select your app version and build for testing and added user will get notification for that.

[image]

Comment: I'd to remove and re-add internal testers. Thanks for the clue btw.